# SVM training OpenCV

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, training-data

I've been using a small number of images (around 20) to train an `SVM`, and I've noticed that when it comes to training, one picture can have a really big difference on the outcome.

Sometimes it will be kind of accurate, other times it'll say everything is a match, other times nothing is a match. Now working with a smaller set of images, I understand that the affects of one image are going to be proportionately greater, but what other than trial and error is there to discern what a good training set is? How do you go about choosing several hundred images for training?

This seems like its a bit *too* important of a step for it to just be left up to going

*"well it seems to run better with these images and not those, now what if I include these..."*

i.e. guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be a broad definitive answer to your question because (as always) it's depending on the specifics of the application scenario.

So **tl;dr** version: Analyze your problem.

3 methods come to mind to gather evidence that your training set is useful:

- Using unsupervised techniques on your training data to verify their usefulness (needs you to actually analyze the problem and define specific criteria).
- Taking training data without selective assumptions but preprocessing them *all* in the same way according to your scenario. This can be anything from a normalization to transfomations in order to ensure that the data grows more stable and e.g. noise or invariance is learnt.
- In certain scenarios (e.g. real-time systems that operate highly diverse data) you don't want to make assumptions. You want your classifier to consider a broad range of input, so you choose your training set broad as well.

In general: If 1 image in your training set breaks your classifier, you need to identify what makes that certain picture special and preferably train with more pictures similar to that one to make it more robust. Unless you can ensure for a fact that the trained system will never encounter images of this type.